# Spark w/ Embedded Kafka: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am attempting embed Kafka/Zookeeper within my test suite for testing Spark as kafka consumer. I create a topic and send a message as follows:

```
val kafkaTestUtils = new KafkaTestUtils
val topic = "test"
kafkaTestUtils.createTopic(topic)
kafkaTestUtils.produceMessage(topic, "test")
```

and consume:

```
// throws org.apache.spark.SparkException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set()

val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](sc, kafkaParams, offsetRanges)
```

Whats interesting is that, after the embedded kafka server is started, no brokers appears to be registered in zookeeper.

```
//returns an empty string
val zk = new ZkClient(zkQuorum, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 10000, ZKStringSerializer)
ZkUtils.getAllBrokersInCluster(zk).map(_.connectionString)
```

Below is my implementation of the embedded kafka (KafkaStartable) and zookeeper.

```
package com.c2fo.atlas.kafka

import java.util.Properties

import kafka.admin.{AdminUtils, TopicCommand}
import kafka.producer.{ProducerConfig, KeyedMessage, Producer}
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient
import org.apache.curator.test.TestingServer
import kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable
import kafka.server.KafkaConfig
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer
import kafka.utils.TestUtils

/**
  * This is a helper class for Kafka test suites. This has the functionality to set up
  * and tear down local Kafka servers, and to push data using Kafka producers.
  *
  */
class KafkaTestUtils {
  val zkServer: TestingServer = new TestingServer(2181)
  zkServer.start()
  val port = TestUtils.choosePort

  val zkClient = new ZkClient(zkServer.getConnectString, 3000,3000, ZKStringSerializer)

  var props = TestUtils.createBrokerConfig(0, port, true)
  props.put("zookeeper.connect", zkServer.getConnectString)
  val config = new KafkaConfig(props)
  val kafkaServer: KafkaServerStartable = new KafkaServerStartable(config)
  kafkaServer.startup()

  val producerProps = TestUtils.getProducerConfig(s"localhost:$port")
  val producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(producerProps)
  val producer = new Producer[String, Array[Byte]](producerConfig)

  def createTopic(topic: String) = {
    AdminUtils.createTopic(zkClient, topic, 1, 1)
  }

  def fetchTopicMetadata(topic: String) : Properties = {
    AdminUtils.fetchTopicConfig(zkClient, topic)
  }

  def produceMessage(topic: String, message: String): Unit = {
    val data = new KeyedMessage[String, Array[Byte]](topic, message.getBytes)
    producer.send(data)
  }

  def teardown() = {
    kafkaServer.shutdown()
    zkClient.close()
    zkServer.close()
  }
}
```

EDIT: Full stacktrace

```
Testing started at 4:59 PM ...
2016-01-18 16:59:42 INFO  ConfigUtil$:31 - Loading config overrides for jenkins
2016-01-18 16:59:44 INFO  ConfigUtil$:31 - Loading config overrides for jenkins
2016-01-18 16:59:45 ERROR DefaultEventHandler:97 - Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: Failed to fetch topic metadata for topic: test
2016-01-18 16:59:46 INFO  ConfigUtil$:31 - Loading config overrides for jenkins
2016-01-18 16:59:46 INFO  ConfigUtil$:31 - Loading config overrides for jenkins
2016-01-18 16:59:46 INFO  ConfigUtil$:31 - Loading config overrides for jenkins

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set()
org.apache.spark.SparkException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set()
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$checkErrors$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:366)
    at scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$.checkErrors(KafkaCluster.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaUtils$$checkOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$createRDD$1.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$createRDD$1.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:709)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createRDD(KafkaUtils.scala:203)
    at com.c2fo.atlas.jobs.batch.reprocess.KafkaIntervalJob$.consume(KafkaIntervalJob.scala:40)
    at com.c2fo.atlas.jobs.Job$$anonfun$delayedInit$1.apply$mcV$sp(Job.scala:22)
```

Comment: what is the stack trace?

Comment: Were you able to find the cause? I am getting a similar error.